# Linux Read Only Partition's data changes

Tags: linux, ext3, ext2, disk-partitioning

I have a read only partition who's data is changing.
The change occurs on the first mount only. Subsequent mounts do not change the partition data.

Tried with ext3 and ext2 incase journalling was an issue ... no help.
Tried tune2fs with -c -1 -i 0 in order to disable updating timestamps or any other data that maybe touched by a check being executed ... no help

Normally I wouldn't care, but I need to hashsum this partition for data integrity purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux can do a write on read-only fs in some rare cases. E.g. when it detects a fs in inconsistent state  (after cold reboot) and is able to do a quick, safe-for-data fix.

I had a kind of such fix when working with Ubuntu Rescue Remix and the write was on second harddrive, before even mounting anything on it (while booting). Information about this was in dmesg, so check the dmesg too.

E.g. here is an `orphan cleanup` possible `on readonly fs`, [it will temporary DISABLE READONLY flag](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.3/fs/ext3/super.c#L1485)

```
1485        if (s_flags & MS_RDONLY) {
1486                ext3_msg(sb, KERN_INFO, "orphan cleanup on readonly fs");
1487                sb->s_flags &= ~MS_RDONLY;
1488        }
... writes...
1549        sb->s_flags = s_flags; /* Restore MS_RDONLY status */
```

This is done in  *ext3_mount->  mount_bdev -> (callback) ext3_fill_super ->  [ext3_orphan_cleanup](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.3/fs/ext3/super.c#L2047)

If the block device is not read-protected itself, linux (ASKING YEAH!)

```
1463        if (bdev_read_only(sb->s_bdev)) {
1464                ext3_msg(sb, KERN_ERR, "error: write access "
1465                        "unavailable, skipping orphan cleanup.");
1466                return;
1467        }
```

WILL COMMIT A WRITE ON READONLY FS

Update: here is a list
http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Forensic_Linux_Live_CD_issues

> Ext3   File system requires journal recovery   To disable recovery: use "noload" flag, or use "ro,loop" flags, or use "ext2" file system type
>
> Ext4   File system requires journal recovery   To disable recovery: use "noload" flag, or use "ro,loop" flags, or use "ext2" file system type
>
> ReiserFS   File system has unfinished transactions     "nolog" flag does not work (see man mount). To disable journal updates: use "ro,loop" flags
>
> XFS    Always (when unmounting)    "norecovery" flag does not help (fixed in recent 2.6 kernels). To disable data writes: use "ro,loop" flags

Comment: EXT3-fs: INFO: recovery required on read only filesystem.
EXT3-fs: write access will be enabled during recovery.
kjournald starting. I'm not clear why it needed to do so, what should be my next step in debugging why it needed to do a recovery?

Comment: Using EXT2 has fixed the problem with my secondary read only partition. The primary still has an issue though, I think it maybe unrelated. It is failing prior to boot into linux. The hashsum is failing when grub runs the check.

Comment: which kind of hashsum? (when the original hash is calculated and stored? when it is checked?)

Comment: When it is checked in grub, the hashsum has already changed. I record the hashsum before mounting the device.